# How to refresh XAML view in MAUI?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I'm making an app where I have layouts generate dynamically based on a list.

```
<StackLayout>
        <CollectionView x:Name="taskList">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Task">
                    <VerticalStackLayout Margin="15">
                        <Entry Text="{Binding name}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                        <Entry Text="{Binding departmentsString}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <HorizontalStackLayout>
                            <Entry Text="{Binding status}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                            <Entry Text="{Binding deadline}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                            <Entry Text="{Binding author.fullName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        </HorizontalStackLayout>
                        <Entry Text="{Binding description}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    </VerticalStackLayout>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>
```

The list is bonded like this:

```
taskList.ItemsSource = company.tasks;
```

I want to refresh this whenever I add new items to the list.

I tried rebinding the list to the `ItemsSource` but it just didn't work:

```
taskList.ItemsSource = company.tasks;
```

How should I do it? Can I just refresh the view so it generates everything again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of assigning the `ItemsSource` from code-behind, you should bind a custom collection, which makes it much easier and decouples the UI and logic. Read more over the [MVVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/maui/mvvm) pattern.

*(I don't have a IDE here, so it's not tested)*

You could do something like:

```
// data class
public class TaskInfo
{
    public string name {get; set;}
    public string departmentsString {get;set;}
}
```

---

```
// you page/view whatever code behind the xaml
public class YourPage : // insert the class which it is derived from.
{
   // create a collection property, which generates events when changed. The UI react on these events.
   public ObservableCollection<TaskInfo> Tasks {get;} = new();

   public YourPage()
   {
      InitComponentsOrSomething();
      // assign the datacontext (which the view binds to)
      this.DataContext = this;
   }
}
```

---

And your xaml would be something like this: *(mind the Binding instead of the name)*

```
<StackLayout>
    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding Tasks}">
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Task">
                <VerticalStackLayout Margin="15">
                    <Entry Text="{Binding name}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                    <Entry Text="{Binding departmentsString}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    <HorizontalStackLayout>
                        <Entry Text="{Binding status}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                        <Entry Text="{Binding deadline}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                        <Entry Text="{Binding author.fullName}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
                    </HorizontalStackLayout>
                    <Entry Text="{Binding description}" IsReadOnly="True" />
                </VerticalStackLayout>
            </DataTemplate>
        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    </CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

---

If you want to add items to the collection, just use the `Tasks` property:

```
Tasks.Add(new TaskInfo { name = "some name", departmentsString = "Enter here" });
```

ps: I would not call a data object 'Task', either give it a better description. TaskInfo/CompanyTask.

Comment: Is it possible to filter the ObservableColletction in a way that it only shows the items based on a searchbar?

Comment: You need to create two Tasks lists. One should be private which is `private ObservableCollection<TaskInfo>_allItems` and `public ObservableCollection<TaskInfo> FilteredTasks {get;} = new();` which you use for binding. When the textBox changes, just refresh the `FilteredTasks` based on the filter over the `_allItems`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use an `IEnumerable` collection that sends property change notifications(such as [ObservableCollection](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.observablecollection-1?view=net-7.0#definition)) for the ItemsSource, then simply add to the underlying collection.
Here's an example:

```cs
ObservableCollection<string> tasks = new();
taskList.ItemsSource = tasks;
tasks.Add("Do something");
```

[Microsoft Reference](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/collectionview/populate-data?view=net-maui-7.0#populate-a-collectionview-with-data-1)